# marking specific ordinates on pandas hist

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib, histogram

I have a Pandas DataFrame of which I plot histogram of counts using DataFrame.hist(), for example

```
my_v['v'].hist(bins=50)
```

Of course, there is a grid, but I would like to add vertical lines for specific values of some ordinates, say at values of df where

```
w0 = 144.0
df=pd.DataFrame(w0/np.arange(1,6))
```

Any clue?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Of course, it is not necessary to use an object as complex as a DataFrame to list values of 144.0/n, n from 1 to something rather small like 5 or 6. It was just to give a line of code to be precise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`axvline`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.axvline) to add vertical lines.

```
# Create some random data
np.random.seed(42)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(list(range(200)), (100,5)), columns=list('abcde'))
```

Plot the histogram on the current figure. Iterate over the array to plot the vertical lines on this existing axes object.

```
w0 = 144.0
df['a'].hist(bins=50, color='g')
for co_ords in np.nditer(w0/np.arange(1,6)):
    plt.axvline(co_ords, color='k')
```

[image]

You can even vary the line-widths/y-axis span limits of the multiple vertical lines by tweaking various keyword arguments to suit your purpose.

Comment: It works and suits perfectly my needs! Thank you very much.